# How to grasp all C# functional features?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm using lambdas in C# a lot (LINQ of many flavours, strongly typed helpers in ASP.NET MVC, AutoMapper API etc), but I can't start to use C# functional features in my own code, because I can't figure out what cool things I can do with them. I use them intuitively most of the time.

Is there any reference or quick (but full) guide about this. I'm not looking for MSDN reference, but for quick explanation of C# all functional features as a whole. If it can be narrowed down for a list with a few links to blog posts -- it is acceptable too.

**Update after question was closed**: It seems my long explanation was no clear, so I'll try to narrow it down: I need a list of concepts I can use to write my own code (not consume other's APIs). The acceplted answer is what I need, thanks.

Comment: Use them. Yup. That's *the* trick.

Comment: This question is a bit like asking for a full guide of how to use your legs. The subject is vast and possibilities endless...

Comment: If you haven't done so already, use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Follow the suggestions and you will learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a nice CodeProject article that explains the functional features introduced in C#. It also has easy to understand examples for each feature:

[Functional programming in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/375166/Functional-programming-in-Csharp)

The article provides explanations and examples for functions and first-class values:

- Function types - delegates, generic function types, predicates, actions
- Function values - storing and passing functions as parameters
- Function arithmetic - adding and subtracting functions

After that, the article talks about functional programming in C#, covering these points:

- Using functions to create generic constructs
- Using LINQ
- High-order functions - functions that handle other functions, function composition
- Asynchronous functions - explains `BeginInvoke`, `IsCompleted`, `EndInvoke`, and using asynchronous functions with callbacks
- Tuples - dynamic data structures
- Closures - explains the scope of variables in delegates and lambda functions, and also explains sharing data and caching
- Recursion using high-order functions
- Partial functions - reducing the number of function arguments using default values
- Curry functions - breaking an N argument function into N single argument functions

Comment: Nice article, looks like a good start int the matter

Comment: Please consider adding a summary (e.g. bullets of main concepts/constructs) and/or relevant excerpts "bare links" are better as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the article linked to by Ove, because I didn't see that aspect explicitly covered:

The use of functional constructs allows separating the sequence of execution from the sequence of how the code is written down. This is because calling a defined lambda may happen at some other time than the time where the program gets to know the lambda.

This can sometimes be a bit unintuitive (deferred execution in LINQ), but generally gives you freedom to keep associated code together even though it runs at different times.